# Facebook deferred deep linking not working when ad preview is clicked

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking, deferred

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>


        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "memoryc://cerebrotrial” -->
            <data
                android:host="cerebrotrial"
                android:scheme="memoryc" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

When I test my ad from the Ad Helper in Facebook, the deferred link is successfully transmitted. But when I click the ad preview from the Facebook app, the deferred deep link is null. I try to catch the deep-link with the below implementations. I first try to get the deep link from the `AppLinkData`, then from the most basic `getIntent()` implementation and finally by the `bolts.Applinks`. The `ApplinkData` is null, the intent does not return anything and the `targetUrl` is null.

```
    // Suggested Facebook implementation
    FacebookSdk.setAutoInitEnabled(true);
    FacebookSdk.fullyInitialize();
    AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(this,
            new AppLinkData.CompletionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched(AppLinkData appLinkData) {
                    // Process app link data
                    if (appLinkData != null) {
                        ConfigAPI.setRefererURL(appLinkData.getTargetUri().toString());
                        JsonObject jsonParams = ConfigAPI.getPayLoad();
                        new CallAPI(jsonParams).execute();
                    }
                }
            }
    );


    //persist deep link data
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Uri data = intent.getData();
    if (data != null) {
        Log.i("DEEP LINK", data.toString());
        ConfigAPI.setRefererURL(data.toString());
        JsonObject jsonParams = ConfigAPI.getPayLoad();
        new CallAPI(jsonParams).execute();
    }

    // using the bolts.Applinks
    Uri targetUrl = AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent(this, getIntent());
    if (targetUrl != null) {
        ConfigAPI.setRefererURL(targetUrl.toString());
        JsonObject jsonParams = ConfigAPI.getPayLoad();
        new CallAPI(jsonParams).execute();
    }
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue or this is intended behaviour? Did the deferred deep link work in production?